# ¿Aporta semántica el encerrar los enlaces de un nav dentro de un ul?

Tags: html, nav, semantic-ui, semantic-html

Suelo hacer la navegación de mis sitios web usando la etiqueta `nav` y directamente agrego los enlaces dentro del mismo:

```html
<nav>
  <a>Inicio</a>
  <a>Etiquetas</a>
  <a>Topics</a>
  <a>Nosotros</a>
</nav>
```

Sin embargo, he observado que algunas personas recomiendad el uso de `ul's` dentro del `nav`, supongo que para dar a entender que los enlaces forman parte de una lista:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a>Etiquetas</a></li>
    <li><a>Topics</a></li>
    <li><a>Nosotros</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Personalmente se me hace más engorroso este segundo método ya que hay que agregar más código css y html.

Volviendo al tema, ¿Agrega el uso de listas dentro de un `nav` valor semántico? ¿Deberíamos usar o no las listas dentro de un nav?

Answer (score 1):

según mi experiencia la respuesta es no, la semantica la agrega el elemento `nav` ya que los navegadores y lectores de pantalla utilizan las etiquetas principales para determinar si omitir o renderizar de forma inicial ese contenido, pero si necesitas crear una navegación de multiples niveles sí es buena practica usar `ul`. ya que ayuda a saber cual es el elemento principal de la sublista. y a esto agregarle las propiedades de aria que corresponen

los elementos semánticos más tomados en cuenta son los siguientes: `<article>, <aside>, <nav>, <section>, <footer>, <header> y <main>`

puedes tomar mejor referencia en este enlace de w3school: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp